# How does the one hot encoding work in Keras image data generator?

Tags: python, keras, image-classification

so I have 3 classes for images, cat, cow and dog.

```
test_batches_1 = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=test_path_1, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog','cow'], batch_size=10, shuffle=False)
```

when I do

```
test_batches_1.class_indices
```

I get this

```
{'cat': 0, 'dog': 1, 'cow': 2}
```

And when I do this: -

```
test_imgs1, test_labels1 = next(test_batches_1)
print(test_labels1)
```

I get this: -

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
```

Which i correct as I have 2 cat, 2 dog and 4 cow pictures.
However, I don't understand why is 0 for cat shown as 1,0,0? or 1 for dog shown as 0,1,0 and 2 for cow shown as 0,0,1?
Can anyone please help with the logic?

Answer (score 0):

cause :

- the index of "1" in the array [ 1,0,0] is  0
- the index of "1" in the array [ 0,1,0] is  1
- the index of "1" in the array [ 0,0,1] is  2

and `test_batches_1.class_indices` displays indices of classes , so the first class is 0th index ...ect

Comment: 0th position, 1st position and 2nd position...thanks